# Search last / and print next 2 characters and whole line

Tags: linux, text-processing, text-formatting

I have a file `abc.log`

```
abc01        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fo027146
abc02        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fb027146
abc03        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fc027146
```

I need to find last /(slash) in every line & then pick next 2 characters and print whole line.

My output should be

```
abc01        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fo
abc02        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fb
abc03        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fc
```

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '.*/..' abc.log
abc01        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fo
abc02        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fb
abc03        /opt/app/ggs/ggs/12.1.2.1.10/dirdat/fc
```

This prints the everything up to (and including) the last `/` plus the next two characters.

Comment: Thank you Freddy. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

using a while read loop and P.E.

```
while read -r line; do
  line0=${line##*/}
  printf '%s\n' "$line/${line0:0:2}"
done < abc.log
```

It will be slow on large set of file size, input